# How to use the `map` function with a ballerina stream?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a stream of person records. I need to convert this to a stream of employee records. How can I achieve this using the `map` function?

The type definition are as below.

```
type Person record {|
    string name;
    int age;
|};

type Employee record {|
    string name;
    string company;
|};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a similar operation as with other map functions.

```
Person[] persons = [{name: "John", age: 30}, {name: "Mary", age: 25}];

// convert the array to a stream
stream<Person> personStream = persons.toStream();

// map each person to an employee and create a new stream of employees
stream<Employee> employeeStream = personStream.'map(function (Person p) returns Employee {
   Employee e = {
      name: p.name,
      company: "WSO2"  
   };
   return e;
});
```

Also you can always refer to the ballerina API docs as well. Here the API docs [link](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.stream/0.4.0#%27map).

Another thing that will help is you can hover your cursor on the `map` function and you can see function definition along with examples. Here is SS of what I have mentioned.

[image: hover on map function]